# Obtain a vertex after a transform in OpenGL?

Tags: c, opengl, glut

I have the following piece of code:

```
#include <gl/glut.h>
#include <stdio.h>


GLfloat xf, yf, win;
GLint view_w, view_h;

//auxiliary vector
GLfloat aux[6] = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 };
GLfloat vertices[768] = { 0.0 };
//count for aux vector
int count = 0;

//Meant to be used for drawing different shapes, store the number of vertecies for each primitive
int primitives[64] = {};

//Index
int vIndex = 0;
int pIndex = 0;

bool flag = false;

//Dedraws the scene using the vertices vector
void Redisplay()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glFlush();     
    int j = 0;
        int k;
        for (int i = 0; i < pIndex; i++)
        {
            glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
            glLoadIdentity();
            glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
            k = j;
            for(; j < k + 2*primitives[i];j+=2)
                glVertex2f(vertices[j], vertices[j + 1]);
            glEnd();
            glFlush();

        }
}

//Store vertices in the vertices vector
void storePrimitive(GLfloat *vector, int nVertex)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < nVertex * 2; i++)
        vertices[vIndex++] = vector[i];
    primitives[pIndex++] = nVertex;
}

//Draw scene
void draw(void)
{
    if (count > 5)
    {
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadIdentity();
        //If flag is true, apply a transform
        if (flag)
        {
            glPushMatrix();
            glScalef(2, 2, 1);
        }
        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        glVertex2f(aux[0], aux[1]);
        glVertex2f(aux[2], aux[3]);
        glVertex2f(aux[4], aux[5]);
        storePrimitive(aux, 3);
        if (flag)
            glPopMatrix();
        glEnd();
        glFlush();
        count = 0;
        flag = false;
    }
}

void init(void)
{
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    xf = 50.0f;
    yf = 50.0f;
    win = 250.0f;
}

void resize(GLsizei w, GLsizei h)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
    view_w = w;
    view_h = h;

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(-win, win, -win, win);
}

void keyboardFunc(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
    switch (key) {
    case 'r': //Clears the screen
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glFlush();
        break;
    case 'd': //Redraw scene
        Redisplay();
        break;
    case 't': //Apply a transform to the next primitive
        flag = true;
        break;
    }
}

void mouse(int button, int state, int x, int y)
{

    if (button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON)
        if (state == GLUT_DOWN) {        
            aux[count] = ((2 * win * x) / view_w) - win;
            count++;
            aux[count] = (((2 * win) * (y - view_h)) / -view_h) - win;
            count++;
        }
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(650, 600);
    glutInitWindowPosition(10, 10);
    glutCreateWindow("Example");
    glutDisplayFunc(draw);
    glutReshapeFunc(resize);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboardFunc);
    glutMouseFunc(mouse);
    init();
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

You can see that it is possible to apply a transform to a primitive in the draw function. What I want to do, however, is to store the vertices of the transformed primitive in the vertices vector. Is it possible to do so without resorting to manually applying the transform to each vertex?

Comment: Into what _space_ do you want to transform the vertex data? The legacy `GL_FEEDBACK` render mode will only get you to window space.

Comment: @derhass I *think* I am working with only window space. In other words, with everything that is visible on the window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it it possible using OpenGL's [Transform Feedback](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Transform_Feedback).
<s>However, I see you are using old style OpenGL, and Transform Feedback is only available since OpenGL 3.0. The new OpenGL style is very very different. If you want to use TransformFeedback you would need to delete all your code and start from scratch.</s>

OP found the way to capture TransformFeedback from `glBegin/End`: https://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter13.html#name2

Comment: Would it be possible to do that using feedback mode as described here (https://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter13.html#name2)?

Comment: @RaphaelSauer It would seem so.

Comment: @RaphaelSauer Yes! I didn't know is was possible to capture TransformFeedback from glBegin/End. Very interesting article, thanks for sharing.